# localStorage value turns back into zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I made some kind a game using HTML, CSS, JS, AJAX AND PHP.

However, in order to save the user's best score, I used localStorage (for the first time).

For some reason, even though the best score is being displayed in the "best score" box while the user 
is still playing (as I wanted), it's being removed when you refresh the page, and turns into 0 again (which
I defined as the default value).

Can someone please point at the problem for me?

Here is the specific part of the code:

```
$(".pi_tab .best_result #score").html(localStorage.record);

$("#pi_input").keyup(function() { // On pressing a digit
    var num = parseInt($("#counter").html()); // Convert counter's value to integer
    if (!isNaN(num)) // If it's a legal number
    {
        if (num + 1 > localStorage.record) // If it's the score is a new record
        {
            localStorage.record = num + 1; // Update record
            $(".pi_tab .best_result #score").html(localStorage.record); // Show record as "Best Score"
        }

    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this code pattern from w3schools: [http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5%5fwebstorage.asp)

Use `setItem` and `getItem` to set/get the data, in my opinion your code is creating another property on localStorage object called record which more likely same as other javascript variable

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the property [`setItem`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5%5fwebstorage.asp) :

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

#### UPDATE

> **Note**: Name/value pairs are always stored as strings. Remember to convert them to another format when needed!

Source : [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5%5fwebstorage.asp)

---

You execute :

```
if (num + 1 > localStorage.getItem("record")) // If it's the score is a new record
{
    localStorage.setItem("record",num + 1);
    ...
}
```

Maybe it's your problem.

Replace by :

```
var record = num + 1;
var localRecord = localStorage.getItem("record");

if (record > parseInt(localRecord)) // If it's the score is a new record
{
    localStorage.setItem("record", record);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sadly, still doesn't work for me. Should I use cookies instead?

Comment: Local Storage is available in all recent browsers. Tchek if you have any error message in your web console (like firebug).